java.lang.ClassCastException: class [Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to class [Ljava.lang.Comparable;
I have defined a generic class for that implements a sorted list using an array. Here is the class:
public class SortedListArray<T extends Comparable<T>> {
/*
 * This class implements the sorted list in java using the array data structure.
 */

private final int DEFCAP = 20; // default capacity of the list
private T[] elements; // array to store the elements
private int numElements;

// some variables for internal use: these will be used by the contains and remove method
private boolean isFound;
private int location;

// constructors
public SortedListArray() {
    elements = (T[]) new Object[DEFCAP];
    numElements = 0;
}

public SortedListArray(int CUSTOMCAP) {
    elements = (T[]) new Object[CUSTOMCAP];
    numElements = 0;
}

// helper functions
public int size() {
    return numElements;
}

public boolean isFull() {
    return (numElements == elements.length);
}

public boolean isEmpty() {
    return (numElements == 0);
}

private void find(T element) {
    /*
     * This method loops through the list and checks if the provided element is present.
     * To optimize the searching process, it implements a binary search algorithm
     * Over here, we implement the algorthim in an iterative way, reason being, the number of elements in the array is going to be large, around 500-1000, for which, an iterative approach will be more efficient.
     */
    // resetting the isFound and location variables from previous runs
    isFound = false;
    location = 0;

    int mid; // storing the middle index of the array
    int low = 0;
    int high = elements.length-1;

    // lopping through
    while (low <= high) {
        // set the mid
        mid = (low + high)/2;

        // check the element at mid
        if (elements[mid].compareTo(element)==0) {
            // updating the location and setting the isFound method to true
            isFound = true;
            location = mid;
            return ;
        } else {
            if (elements[mid].compareTo(element)<0) {
                high = mid - 1;
            } else {
                low = mid + 1;
            }
        }
    }
    return;
}

// publically accessible search method
public int search(T element) {
    /*
     * This is the publically accessible method that can be used by the users to see if an element is present in a list or not.
     * Internally, it uses the find method.
     */
    // calling the find method
    find(element);
    // if found, return index
    if (isFound==true) {
        return location;
    } else {
        return -1; // since not found, return -1.
    }
}

// setter functions
// helper function for add
private void addNShift(int loc, T element) {
    /*
     * This method takes in an element, and the location its to be added to and adds the element to that position. It also moves all the elements to the next position and then adds the element to the location
     */
    // looping backwards from end to loc+1 th index
    for (int i=numElements; i>loc; i--) {
        //shifting element to the right
        elements[i] = elements[i-1];
    }
    // once its done, update the loc index
    elements[loc] = element;
}

// add
public boolean add(T element) {
    /*
     * This method adds the provided element to the correct posistion in the list.
     */

    // error checks
    if (isFull()==true) {
        System.out.println("The array is full, cant add new elements in the array.");
        return false;
    }
    // if the array is empty, we can just add the first one and stop
    if (isEmpty()==true) {
        elements[0] = element;
        numElements += 1;
        return true;
    } 
    // looping across the list, and finding the appropriate place to add the element
    else {
        // loop over the list, and find the appropriate position
        int loc = 0;
        while (loc<numElements) {
            if (elements[loc].compareTo(element)>=0) {
                // add the element in this position, and move all elements to the right
                addNShift(loc, element);
                numElements+=1;
                return true;
            } else {
                // update loc
                loc += 1;
            }
        }
        return false; // if 
    }
}

// the remove method
public boolean remove(T element) {
    /*
     * This method removes the given element from the list, if its found.
     */
    // check if the element is present
    find(element);
    // if present, remove it and shift every succeeding element to the left by 1.
    if (isEmpty()==true) {
        throw new EmptyListException("The list is empty!");
    }
    if (isFound==true) {
        // remove and shift
        removeNShift(location);
        numElements -= 1;
        return true;
    } else {
        System.out.println("The target element is not present in the list.");
        return false;
    }
}

private void removeNShift(int location) {
    /*
     * This method takes in the index which needs to be removed, removes it by shifting each succeeding element one place to the left and sets the last element to null.
     */
    // if the location is the last element, then just set it to null
    if (location==numElements-1) {
        elements[location] = null;
    } else {
        // looping through the list, starting from index location
        for (int i=location; i<numElements-1;i++) { // need to only do this till the second last element
            // replacing the current element with the next one
            elements[i] = elements[i+1];
        }

        // finally, we need to set the final element to null
        elements[numElements-1] = null;
    }
}

}
And when I instantiate this class, which I do like this:
private SortedListArray<Integer> ArraySortedListInt;
ArraySortedListInt = new SortedListArray<Integer>(sortedArray.length);
But when I do this, I get the following error:
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: class [Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to class [Ljava.lang.Comparable; ([Ljava.lang.Object; and [Ljava.lang.Comparable; are in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap')
How do I solve this issue? I am doing this as part of my assignment, which asks me to only have generic classes. I have also tried to make this change in the class constructor
public SortedListArray(Class dtype) {
    elements = (T[]) Array.NewInstance(dtype, DEFCAP);
    numElements = 0;
}

But this also does not work.
Please help

I don't see ArraySortedListInt inside the code you have pasted.

Hello Aman, change T[¨] to List.

Generics and arrays don't work together. Given that you've chosen to use an array as backing store (instead of, for example, a java.util.ArrayList), your array should just be of type Object[]. It cannot be of type T[] - that is a lie. The code you wrote needs to know what T is as you write it, which you don't (that's the point of generics). Generics aren't 'reified', which means: The code you write that uses generics does not know what they are and cannot know what they are, it's more like a math formula, it's like reasoning: You're telling the compiler: Let's just hypothetically say there is some type. We shall call it T.
And the compiler takes it from there.
For example, the compiler is capable of figuring out that the following code is 'safe' as long as nobody does anything crazy:
class Wrapper<T> {
  T value;

  public void set(T value) {
    this.value = value;
  }

  public T get() {
    return value;
  }
}

When you write Wrapper<String> w = new Wrapper<String>();, that instance of Wrapper has no idea that you've chosen String. It's all a figment of the compiler. The compiler reasons out that the code is 'safe' - it is fine if code that uses Wrapper (calls new Wrapper, w.get, and w.set) gets to assume that get() is as if it returns the type you made it with, that won't ever 'go wrong'. But, the actual code of Wrapper (as in, the class file) is just Object. The compiler silently inserts the checks and casts to make this work for you.
In contrast, arrays are reified. Given:
<W> void whatDoesItWrap(Wrapper<W> wrapper) {
  /// ????
}

Wrapper<String> w = new Wrapper<String>();
whatDoesItWrap(w);

You cannot write that method. It is not possible. Whereas with arrays, which are reified, you can write that method:
void whatDoesItWrap(Object[] arr) {
  System.out.println(arr.getClass().getComponentType());
}

String[] s = new String[10];
whatDoesItWrap(s);

That would print java.lang.String.
This is a significant part of the reason why arrays and generics are really different in this regard, and that leads to: They do not play well together. T[] implies the array itself knows what T is, which it can't here, so it's a lie.
To fix the lie, just make that Object[]. Instead, all public facing methods you have should cast. Yes, those casts are also a lie (the compiler generates no code for a cast to (T) - it does not know what T is, hence, it can't check), but it's you injecting 'I know you lost the plot and can no longer reason out that it is all safe and cannot go wrong, but I am smarter than you and I can determine this. So just trust me and shut up'.
Hence you end up at something like this:
class Wrap2Things<W> {
  Object[] theThings = new Object[2]; // Not `W[]`!

  void setThingOne(W a) {
    theThings[0] = a;
  }

  void setThingTwo(W b) {
    theThings[1] = b;
  }

  W getThingOne() {
    return (W) theThings[0]; // compiler warning
  }

  W getThingTwo() {
    return (W) theThings[1]; // compiler warning
  }
}

The warnings are the compiler telling you: Well, I'm going to have to take your word for it. No ClassCastException would occur in this line if you're wrong, you know.
This is, in fact, how java's very own ArrayList is built, and it is how you should build your code.
Note that Object[] as a typeref is magic and allows any object. This leads to invalid type analysis but arrays predate that sort of nuanced thinking (arrays have been with java since 1.0; generics were introduced a decade later, in 1.5).
It explains why it 'works' when you just have class Foo<T> (because T gets erased to Object) but it does not with class Foo<T extends SomethingOtherThanObject>.
